# Multiple Random numbers per material

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, mathematics

I want to randomize several procedural textures in the same material. For example, have 3 different Noise textures with a random number as their Scale. I can use the Random output of the Object Info node, but this gives me the same random number each time.

Is there a way to get more random numbers?

Comment: The random output of the object info node is a random number for each object, not for each output. I don't believe there is a way to do what you're looking for without hard coding in values, but I might be wrong.

Comment: Could you use a script node and get a random value from Python?

Comment: the script node is for OSL and not python